# Are there any examples (real life cases) of invalid FMS data affecting flight operations?

Tags: instrument-procedures

Do you know of any real life cases, when invalid FMS data affected somehow the flight operations?

By invalid FMS data I mean a case, when the procedure coding does not reflect properly the original procedure as published by state's AIP service.

Related question: [What happens with RNAV procedures on the way from AIP publication to FMS database](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/19386/what-happens-with-rnav-procedures-on-the-way-from-aip-publication-to-fms-databas)

Answer (score 2):

Here is some old material used in Europe to prepare for the transition from AIS to AIM: [AIS to AIM: Enabling the Net-Centric Information Environment](http://www.icao.int/safety/information-management/Transition%20Library%20for%20AIM/Documentation/Legal%20and%20Institutional%20Issues.pdf) by Roderick van Dam, Head of Eurocontrol Legal Service. The document references two legal cases where navigational data and hardware were involved.

Pakistan International Airlines

> Bejon v. Pakistan International  Airlines (Toulouse Court of 
>   Appeal, 1998) Liability of Jeppesen raised.  Jeppesen argued that
>   approach map  was based on map provided by States.  Court concluded
>   that map was  technically acceptable This case confirmed  the risk
>   related to  the publication of Aeronautical data.

More: [PIA Flight 268](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PIA_Flight_268).

American Airlines

> American Airlines v. Jeppesen- Anderson and Honeywell (US Federal 
>   Court, 2000) The Accident Report had concluded: the probable causes
>   of the accident were  related to failures of  the flight crew; 
>   contributing factor was related to FMS-generated navigational
>   information; AA blamed the Jeppesen software in the  Honeywell
>   computer; alleged that products  helped caused the crash; A Federal
>   Jury found  that Jeppesen was  17% at fault and Honeywell 8 % at
>   fault.

More: [American Airlines Flight 965](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Airlines_Flight_965).